# (In)equivalent Trivializations of Vector Bundle

Tags: manifolds, vector-bundles

Given a trivial rank-$n$ vector bundle $V$ over a manifold $M$, there are many different trivializations of $V$, *i.e.* many possible choices of nowhere-dependent sections $\phi_1, \ldots \phi_n$.  My question is,

> What notions of "equivalent" and "inequivalent" are there for trivializations of $V$?

I am specifically interested in the case where $V = TM$, that is, parallelizable manifolds.  In this restricted setting my question could be rephrased as,

> When some construction starts with the phrase "Fix a trivialization $TM \cong M \times \mathbb R^n$..." then in what situations do I need to worry about the choice of trivialization?

(That's a pretty open-ended question but I'm interested in hearing any example that comes to your mind.  Thanks)